# Spectral clustering on sparse dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, cluster-analysis, spectral-clustering

I am applying spectral clustering (`sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering`) on a dataset with quite some features that are relatively sparse. When doing spectral clustering in Python, I get the following warning:

`UserWarning: Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding may not work as expected. warnings.warn("Graph is not fully connected, spectral embedding"`

This is often followed by an error like this one:

```
`
File "****.py", line 120, in perform_clustering_spectral_clustering
  predicted_clusters = cluster.SpectralClustering(n_clusters=n).fit_predict(features)
File "****\sklearn\base.py", line 349, in fit_predict
  self.fit(X)
File "****\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line 450, in fit
  assign_labels=self.assign_labels)
File "****\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line 256, in spectral_clustering
  eigen_tol=eigen_tol, drop_first=False)
File "****\sklearn\manifold\spectral_embedding_.py", line 297, in spectral_embedding
  largest=False, maxiter=2000)
File "****\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\lobpcg\lobpcg.py", line 462, in lobpcg
  activeBlockVectorBP, retInvR=True)
File "****\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\lobpcg\lobpcg.py", line 112, in _b_orthonormalize
  gramVBV = cholesky(gramVBV)
File "****\scipy\linalg\decomp_cholesky.py", line 81, in cholesky
  check_finite=check_finite)
File "****\scipy\linalg\decomp_cholesky.py", line 30, in _cholesky
  raise LinAlgError("%d-th leading minor not positive definite" % info)
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 9-th leading minor not positive definite
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 9-th leading minor not positive definite
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: the leading minor of order 12 of 'b' is not positive definite. The factorization of 'b' could not be completed and no eigenvalues or eigenvectors were computed.`
```

However, this warning/error does not always occur when using the same settings (i.e. its behaviour is not very consistent, making it hard to test). It occurs for different values of n_clusters, but it happens more often for values n=2 and n > 7 (that is my brief experience at least; as I mentioned, its behaviour is not very consistent).

How should I cope with this warning and related error? Does it depend on the amount of features? What if I add more?

Comment: I assume you are using `sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering`? You really need to mention this in the question. Also, please show the full tracebacks for the error and the warning, not just the last line.

Comment: Is your sparse similarity matrix *positive definite*?

Comment: I edited the post with the requested information. The matrix probably is not positive definite (since that is what the error says). The question is how to cope with it?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem with n_clusters. As this is unsupervised ML there is no single correct value for n_clusters. In your case it seems like n_cluster lies between 3 and 7. Assuming you have some ground truth to clustering best way to handle would be to try few values of n_cluster to see  if any pattern emerges for given data set while making sure to avoid any over-fitting. 
You may also use silhouette coefficient (sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score)